# How to get the autocomplete for HTML in Notepad++

Tags: html, autocomplete, notepad++

I was editing my site in Notepad++ when I entered a **D** and a list with all the HTML tags that started with the letter **D** appeared.

How do I do that again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your tag and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. A list with possible elements will pop up.